# A question about path info

Tags: httpwebrequest, pathinfo

`domain.name/index.php/pathinfo.php` works

but `domain.name/image.jpg/pathinfo.php` will give a `404`, where `domain.name/image.jpg` DOES exists,why?

Answer (score 0):

Because they're different URLs, and the server is responding 404 to one?

Comment: It seems you don't know about path info?

Comment: @wamp, those URLs could mean anything.  It depends how server is setup.  For many MediaWiki installations, the first will take you to the article on Pathinfo.php while the second is a 404.  If you have more info, you should provide it.